# In Swift, is the count of an instance of String.CharacterView always equal to the distance between the startIndex and endIndex in all cases?

Tags: swift, string, indexof

The title says it all.  In Swift, is the count of an instance of String.CharacterView always equal to the distance between the startIndex and endIndex in all cases?

**Swift 2.3:**

string.characters.count == string.characters.startIndex.distanceTo(string.characters.endIndex)

**Swift 3:**

string.characters.count == string.characters.distance(from:string.characters.startIndex, to:string.characters.endIndex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is a requirement of `Collection`. It is mandatory that iterating from `startIndex` to `endIndex` exactly cover all the elements. The number of steps that would take (the distance) must be equivalent to `count` or you would violate that requirement.